# Add Lattitude / Longitude search widget to a Shiny Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet

I am looking to add a Lattitude / Longitude search widget to a Shiny leaflet map.   I found a workable leaflet js solution [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213465/zoom-to-coordinate-from-form-input-in-leaflet) , and I would like to port the js function into my R Shiny application.  Using the htmlwidgets onRender function with panTo, I can get the map to pan to specific coordinates; however,I want a user to be able to type in lat and long and zoom to that location on the map. Here is the code for a sample map that I have been using to test potential solutions.  I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to apply the submitted coordinates to the map. The commented out code in the onRender is one of my attempts. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
            library(shiny)
            library(leaflet)

            ui <- fluidPage(leafletOutput("mymap"),

                            tags$div(
                              HTML(
                                '
                                Latitude: <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat"/>
                                Longitude: <input type="text" name="lng" id="lng"/>
                                <input type="button" onclick="zoomTo()" value="zoomTo"/>
                                '
                              )
                              ))

            server <- function(input, output, session) {
              output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
                leaflet() %>%
                  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                                   options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
                  setView(15, 47, 12) %>%
                  htmlwidgets::onRender(
                    'function(el, x) {                        
                    this.panTo(new L.LatLng(26, -80));                        
                    #var lat = document.getElementById("lat").value;
                    #var lng = document.getElementById("lng").value;
                    #this.panTo(new L.LatLng(lat, lng));


              }'
            )
            })
              }

            shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By referring to `input$zoomTo` in the `renderLeaflet` statement, Shiny re-runs that function if you click the button. To make it work, I had to assign the button an `id` and the correct `class`.

I am not sure why you use HTML and JavaScript to do all this instead of using the widgets provided by Shiny. Take a look at the [Shiny Widget Gallery](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/widget-gallery.html) to see what's possible using just R functionality.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(leafletOutput("mymap"),

                tags$div(
                    HTML(
                        '
                                Latitude: <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat"/>
                                Longitude: <input type="text" name="lng" id="lng"/>
                                <input id="zoomTo" type="button" value="zoomTo"  class="action-button"/>
                                '
                    )
                ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
        input$zoomTo

        leaflet() %>%
            addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                             options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
            setView(15, 47, 12) %>%
            htmlwidgets::onRender(
                'function(el, x) {                        
                    var lat = document.getElementById("lat").value;
                    var lng = document.getElementById("lng").value;
                    this.panTo(new L.LatLng(lat, lng));
              }'
            )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks Basibo1!   I was able to implement your solution.  And your comment about using native shiny widgets helped me realize I was overthinking my problem. I have another version working with lat / long numericInputs tied to the setView in the leaflet function:  observeEvent(input$zoomTo, {
    leafletProxy("mymap") %>%
  setView(input$slat, input$slon, 12 ) 
    
  })